# What is difference between Oracle Advanced Queues(AQs) and Oracle Transactional Event Queues (TEQs)?

Tags: oracle, advanced-queuing

What is difference between Oracle Advanced Queues(AQs) and Oracle Transactional Event Queues (TEQs) from usage/user perspective ?